# UWP Intercept Webview request and add header

Tags: uwp, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml

I'm navigating to a url in UWP webview, the page internally makes many http calls. I'm intercepting those calls via *WebResourceRequested* event. I'm adding auth token in the header, when doing so I'm getting "*application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread*", tried to run  in the current UI's dispatcher but still I face this issue. Please help me on this.

```
 private async void Wb_WebResourceRequested(WebView sender, WebViewWebResourceRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        //_ = this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
        //{

            try
            {
                string host = args.Request.RequestUri.Host;
                string uri = args.Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri;

                    try
                    {
                        var reqMsg = args.Request;
                        reqMsg.Headers.Authorization = new Windows.Web.Http.Headers.HttpCredentialsHeaderValue("Bearer", _AuthToken);
                        var response = await client.SendRequestAsync(reqMsg).AsTask();
                        args.Response = response;

                        Debug.WriteLine(uri + " res code : " + response.StatusCode);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(uri + " error msg : " + e.Message);
                    }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        //});

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to tests, you cannot be in an asynchronous environment when setting `args.Response`.

please change

```cs
var response = await client.SendRequestAsync(reqMsg).AsTask();
```

to:

```cs
var response = client.SendRequestAsync(reqMsg).AsTask().Result;
```

Comment: Does it not have possibility of deadlock as they have mentioned in the .Result side effects @Richard

Comment: The synchronous method does freeze the UI, but if you must use `WebResourceRequested`, you cannot perform asynchronous operations in the event callback

Comment: do we have any other alternate approach for this.

Comment: Generally speaking, `WebResourceRequested` event will listen for the loading of some scripts or resources. The loading of these resources usually does not need to modify the request header. But if the situation is special, you can consider adding a request header to the resource request in `Javascript` instead of intercepting the request through `WebView`.
If you are using a request header when navigating to a page, use [WebView.NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigatewithhttprequestmessage)